# How to find and apply format in multiple sheets in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I would like to find the week number and apply formatting to that cell. The week number is generated automatically using weeknum formula in `Sheets("Program").Range("N3")`.

I have 5 sheets. In 1st sheet `Overview`, the data is in row 8 and the formatting works. In sheet 2 to 5 the data is in row 4. So, I selected all 4 sheets and used the same logic. But the formatting is not working on sheet `BBB`, `CCC`, `DDD`.

My program not showing any error and not working. Can any one help me?

```
Sub FindandFormat()  
    Dim ws1, ws2, ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim CW As String
    Dim rng2, rng1 As Range
    
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AAA")
    
    ' "Format to show the actual week in every sheet"
    CW = "W" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Program").Range("N3").Value - 1
    
    With ws1
        Set rng1 = .Rows("8:8").Find(What:=CW, LookIn:=xlValues)
        With rng1.Interior
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
            .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
        End With
    End With
    
    With ws2
        Set rng2 = .Rows("4:4").Find(What:=CW, LookIn:=xlValues)
    
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD")).Select
    
        With rng2.Interior
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
            .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Might be simpler to just loop over the sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you declare `Dim ws1, ws2, ws3 As Worksheet` only `ws3` is of type `Worksheet` but the others are of type `Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable or they are `Variant` by default: `Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet`. Same for your `Range`.

The issue in this code is that selecting those sheets does nothing but selecting them.

```
With ws2
    Set rng2 = .Rows("4:4").Find(What:=CW, LookIn:=xlValues)

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD")).Select

    With rng2.Interior
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
    End With
End With
```

You apply the format to `With rng2.Interior` and `rng2` references to `.Rows("4:4")…` which uses `With ws2` so clearly applies only to `ws2`! It applies it to `ws2` no matter which worksheets are selected.

Instead you need to loop over your worksheets and apply the format to every worksheet:

```
Dim WorksheetNames As Variant  ' define the worksheet names you want the format to apply to
WorksheetNames = Array("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD")

Dim WorksheetName As Variant
For Each WorksheetName In WorksheetNames  ' loop through all worksheet names in the array
    Dim FoundAt As Range  ' try to find CW in each worksheet
    Set FoundAt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WorksheetName).Rows("4:4").Find(What:=CW, LookIn:=xlValues)
    
    ' check if CW was found otherwise show error message
    If Not FoundAt Is Nothing Then
        With FoundAt.Interior  ' perform format change
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
            .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox """" & CW & """ was not found.", vbOKonly
    End If
Next WorksheetName
```